# Are multiple assignments to unique_ptr valid?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

Are multiple assignments to `unique_ptr<T>` valid? Based on output, it is, but is `T`'s destructor guaranteed to be called when `make_unique()` is used and the return value is assigned to a `unique_ptr` that is already holding existing memory?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class A{
public:
    A(){ std::cout << "Construcor" << std::endl; }
    ~A(){ std::cout << "Destrucor" << std::endl; }
    void foo(){ std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> pointer;
    for(auto i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
        pointer = std::make_unique<A>();
        pointer->foo();
    }
}
```

output:

```
Construcor
foo
Construcor
Destrucor // Destructor is called because first instance of A is out of scope?
foo
Destrucor
```

Comment: Move assigning an instance of `unique_ptr` to another  will replace the previous one which requires the previously held value be destroyed properly (if it's present). Anything else would leak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly valid.

When you assign a new object to a `unique_ptr`, it destroys its current object and takes ownership of the new object. This is expected and documented behavior.

As you can see in your logging, this is exactly what is actually happening:

```
Construcor   (first call to make_unique) 
             (first assignment, nothing to log here) 
foo
Construcor   (second call to make_unique)
Destrucor    (second assignment, first object destroyed)
foo
Destrucor    (main exits, second object destroyed)
```